# jQuery Number to Number scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK, I know you can change a `id` or `class` text using this `$("#test").text("NUMBER_HERE");` but... using jQuery, instead of statically going from one number to the next... is there a way so it counts down or up depending on the number you picked?

Thanks

Comment: Please post an example of HTML and JavaScript you are currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually writing the code, as it looks like you know jQuery already, I think it's the `:contains` keyword you are looking for.

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

So get the number, from the text of the element you selected, and then decrement or increment it by one, use contains and repeat till you get to the target number.

Your question is a little vague so I hope this helps.